# AndroidでSpinnerでLongClick を感知させる方法はありますか？

Tags: java, android

onItemLongClickがspinnerで使えないのは、確認済みです。
このコードのように、Handlerを使って、onTouch()で、1000m秒後にボタンが押されていれば、長押し、として、認めるというコードを書きたいです。
　そして、onItemSelected()で、選択された物のデータを取得して、データベースからdeleteしたいです。
アドバイスをどうぞよろしくお願いします。

```
final Handler actionHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this, "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    };
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
            //  deleteitem = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                actionHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

                //ここで、押してから1秒後にelse ifだったら、ロングクリックと判断して、行動を起こす?

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                actionHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);


            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    //--------------ここからonItemSelect-------------//


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

            //この下２行は正しいとこに
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
            deleteitem = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
            //-------------------------ここで、長押しされた時のaction-------------------//
            //--------------ここで、消していいですか？を確認のダイアログを出力--------------//
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LocationActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_deleteplace_us, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_deleteplace));
            // アラーとダイアログ を生成
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LocationActivity.this);
            builder.setView(layout);
            //---------dailogの削除ボタンを追加、それが押されたらデータベースから削除する--------//
            builder.setPositiveButton("削除", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (deleteitem.equals("GPSの現在地")) {
                    } else if (deleteitem.equals("googlemapで検索")) {
                    } else {
                        String sql = "delete from favorite where  placename  = '" + deleteitem + "' " +
                                "and username = '" + username + "';";
                        System.out.println(sql + "いいいいいいいいいいいいいいいいいいいいい");
                        System.out.println(deleteitem);
                        MyOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper(LocationActivity.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
                        c.moveToFirst();
                        onStart();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Spinnerが、LongCLickできないことがわかりました。

単純な結果となりましたが、質問内容の目的は、満たされましたので、解決済みとさせていただきます